# Remove Body Class After Window Load with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using a CSS class on the body to stop transitions running when the document loads. How can I remove it once the Window has loaded with JavaScript (no jQuery)?

**HTML:**

```
<body class="preload">
```

***css:***

```
.preload * {
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -ms-transition: none !important;
  -o-transition: none !important;
}
```

This would be the jQuery equivalent *except I'm not using jQuery:

```
$("window").load(function() {
  $("body").removeClass("preload");
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
window.addEventListener(
    'load',
    function load()
    {
        window.removeEventListener('load', load, false);
        document.body.classList.remove('preload');
    },
    false);
```

Using `addEventListener` means that it won't interfere with any other event listeners that may be attached by other libs, etc.

The above code will remove the event listener once the event has fired too.

I would have thought the event listener should be on `document` but apparently [that doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16406528/24874).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work in all browsers:

```
window.onload = function () { document.body.className = ""; }
```

Drew's answer is good, but `classList` is [not supported](http://caniuse.com/classlist) in older versions of IE as well as `window.addEventListener`, if that's important.

Comment: True -- `classList` is a nice modern thing that you may not be able to use if your site is internet facing. You can set the empty string to `className` as you show instead if needed.