# Simple click event not firing, console returns impossible or no error at all

Tags: javascript

```
document.addEventListener("load", function()
{
var firstGal = document.querySelector("containsNext");

var nextB = document.querySelector("nondynamic");

nextB.addEventListener('click', function(){ firstGal.style.opacity = 0;});
});
```

This is the function causing the issues, all else runs fine.
I am just testing something before i go on to final layout idea, and want to test if the nondynamic next button works and animates the pic in containsNext on click. Just animating the opacity for test purposes.
If i try to run this without the onload, i get many reference errors and all kinds of undefined elements. Oddly, codepen even gave me errors on some lines which I have deleted hours ago:-)
Ok, so by adding the on load property, there are no errors thrown, but the code does not run.
Am i overlooking the proverbial elephant in the room here?
Both concerned elements are not dynamically created(unlike most of the page).
Thank you guys for the heads up.

Link to the pen:
http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/gPggLB

Comment: I believe query selector should have dots before class names so `var firstGal = document.querySelector(".containsNext"); var nextB = document.querySelector(".nondynamic");`

Comment: @Zefiryn
I have just tried, but does not work either.
I have even tried to give them an ID and use getElementById, and the getElementsByClassName("class")[0];
None of it works.

Comment: Are you sure the code fires? You put it inside load event of document. Depending on place in the page this might attach event but after load was already fired.

Comment: @Zefiryn 
Well, that is the odd thing, if I remove the on load event, I get this:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null, and all the rest of the code does not work anymore.

Comment: Maybe try `window.document.onload = function(e){ ... }` in the head of the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zefiryn is right, you should use . as the selectors are CSS classes and it is more reliable to add the event listener to the object `window`. Please, try this:

```
window.addEventListener( "load", function()
{
    var firstGal = document.querySelector( ".containsNext" );

    var nextB = document.querySelector( ".nondynamic" );

    nextB.addEventListener( 'click', function()
    {

        firstGal.style.opacity = 0;
    } );
} );
```

Check this link also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load and see the note below the example provided.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, you too, same as above.
One question remain, without the load event, the script wouldn't run at all, is that because these lines are at the start of the script, i suppose?

Comment: What I think is happening here is that you need to have the DOM completely loaded on the browser, so you can access the HTML elements from JS. It's not a matter of having the script at the top or the bottom; I always try to put the JS code right before </body> though. That's why you need the load event. That's when you know that the DOM and images are already loaded (for window.load) and then run the code you need to manipulate and play with things. :)

Answer (score 1):

window.addEventListener works better than document.addEventListener based on

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404380/why-doesnt-document-addeventlistenerload-function-work-in-a-greasemonkey-s)

Also, to select your "nondynamic" css selector you need a dot for the class selector:

```
var nextB = document.querySelector(".nondynamic");
```

Finally, querySelector will only return the first element with that class so make sure it's the first one on your page...or provide a unique id for the "Next" element and select based on the id instead like:

```
<div id="yourIdHere" class="nondynamic">Next</div>

var nextB = document.querySelector("#yourIdHere");
```

Comment: Thank you too, esp for this valueable link, it was the document.addEventListener, it all seems to easy when someone finally resolves something:-)

Answer (score 1):

My proposal is:

```js
var arrayIndex = ['url("http://www.croatiaweek.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/photo_twitter_chris_hadfield1.jpg")','url("http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2014/03/07/article-2575552-1C1A7B9400000578-567_964x673.jpg")', 'url("http://www.thegoldenscope.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/vicogargano-1a.jpg")'];


window.addEventListener("load", function()
                        {
  var firstGal = document.getElementsByClassName("containsNext");

  var nextB = document.getElementsByClassName("nondynamic");

  nextB[0].addEventListener('click', function(){

    firstGal[0].style.opacity = 0;});
});



var closingButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("closingButton");
var index = 0, length = closingButtons.length;
for ( ; index < length; index++) {
  closingButtons[index].addEventListener("click",
                                         function () {
    hidePic(this);
  }
                                        );
}

function addImageInto(arrayIndex, container) {
  var displayArea = document.querySelector('.displayArea');
  if (displayArea.querySelector('.' + container.id)) {
    return;
  }
  displayArea.innerHTML = '';


  var previous = document.createElement("div");
  previous.textContent = "Previous";
  previous.style.width = "100px";

  previous.style.height = "20px";
  previous.style.background = "violet";
  previous.className = "prevPic";
  displayArea.appendChild(previous);
  var span = document.createElement("div");
  span.textContent = "Close";
  // could also be firstChild.nodeValue = "Some new label text!";
  span.style.width = "60px";
  span.style.height = "20px";
  span.style.background = "red";
  span.className = "closingButton";
  displayArea.appendChild(span);
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.width = "500px";
  div.style.height = "200px";
  div.style.backgroundImage = arrayIndex;
  div.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
  div.style.backgroundSize = "contain";
  div.style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";

  div.style.boxShadow = "3px 3px 4px blue";
  div.style.margin = "5px auto";
  div.className = "images";
  displayArea.appendChild(div);
  div.style.opacity = 0;

  setTimeout(function() {
    div.style.opacity = 1;
  }, 500);
  span.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();

    var finalTarget = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('images')[0];


    var finalTarget4 = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('closingButton')[0];
    setTimeout(function(){

      var obj1 = finalTarget.style;
      obj1.height = 0;
      obj1.opacity = 0;
      // obj1.width = 0;



      var obj4 = finalTarget4.style;
      obj4.height = 0;
      obj4.opacity = 0;
      obj4.width = 0;
    },1000);
  });


}

function createFunctionClickListener(arrayIndex) {
  // This returns a listener / callback function.
  return function(event) {
    var container = event.currentTarget;
    addImageInto(arrayIndex, container);
  };
}

// Croatia
document.getElementById("newDom").addEventListener("click",   createFunctionClickListener(arrayIndex[0]));

// Spain
document.getElementById("newDom2").addEventListener("click",
                                                    createFunctionClickListener(arrayIndex[1]));

// Italy
document.getElementById("newDom3").addEventListener("click",
                                                    createFunctionClickListener(arrayIndex[2]));
```

```css
body{width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-image: url('http://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/55000/55167/earth_lights_lrg.jpg');
  background-size:100% 100%;
  z-index:-1;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: right top;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
h2{text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  text-shadow:2px 1px 2px silver;}
button{border: #000 solid 1px;
  box-shadow:2px 2px 2px blue;
  background:transparent;
  color:white;
  font-size:1em;
  font-weight:400;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
  padding:2px 7px;}

.images{transition:1s;!important;}
.images:hover{
  transform: translate(0px,-30px)scale(1.1);!important;
}
.closingButton{font-size:1em;
  color:white;
  padding-top:3px;
  box-shadow:2px 2px 1px purple;
  margin:2px auto;
  text-align:center;}

.prevPic{font-size:1em;
  color:white;
  padding-top:3px;
  box-shadow:2px 2px 1px purple;
  position:relative;
  top:27px;
  text-align:center;}
.nondynamic{width:100px;
  font-size:1em;
  color:white;
  padding-top:3px;
  box-shadow:2px 2px 1px white;
  position:relative;
  top:50px;left:70%;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;}


.displayArea{width:500px;
  margin:10px auto;}

.containsNext{
  border:2px white solid;
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
  z-index:100;position:relative;top:-190px;
  transform:rotateX(10deg);
  margin:10px auto;
  background:url(http://www.pxleyes.com/images/contests/croatia%20beach/fullsize/croatia%20beach_4c51a7c40c71c_hires.jpg);
  background-size:100% 100%;}
```

```html
<h2 id="header">Creating elements with native JS and prototype/inheritance practice</h2>
<div class="nondynamic">Next</div>
<button id="newDom">Croatia</button>
<button id="newDom2">Spain</button>
<button id="newDom3">Italia</button>
<button id="newDom4">Sweden</button>
<button id="newDom31">France</button>
<button id="newDom32">France</button>
<button id="newDom33">France</button>
<button id="newDom34">France</button>
<button id="newDom35">France</button>
<button id="newDom36">France</button>
<button id="newDom37">France</button>
<button id="newDom38">France</button>
<div class="displayArea"></div>
<div class="containsNext"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was literally the window on load vs document on load that caused this.
I will upvote all of you guys:-)