# why document.addEventListener() is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am trying to execute the document.addEventListener() but it is not working why ?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>javascript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\SUDARSHAN\Desktop\html_UI\eventstyle.css">
</head>

<body>
    <p id="p1">Welcome</p>
</body>
<script>
  
function f1() {
    document.getElementById("p1").style.fontSize="50px";
}

document.addEventListener("load",f1);
console.log("hello");

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404380/why-doesnt-document-addeventlistenerload-function-work-in-a-greasemonkey-s

Comment: maybe you try `window.addEventListener("load", f1)`

Comment: or try `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",f1)`

Comment: `load` occurs on `window`, but not on `document`.

Answer (score 2):

You must append a `load` listener to `window` instead of `document`.

```
window.addEventListener("load",f1);
```

That being said, you cannot have a `script` element as a child of the `html` element, it must be in the `head` or `body` (which are the only allowed children of `html`). Always make sure your HTML is valid at all times; invalid HTML puts you in unspecified territory and tends to make things unpredictable (even if things *seem* to work).

Answer (score 0):

Flaws in above code.

1. Always make sure the `html` tag documented correctly. For ref https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp
2. `load` event depends on window. In above code, you added the listener for document.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', f1);
```

There are two events which are related to loading and unloading of the `Document`

1. DOMContentLoaded
2. readystatechange

Refer this page for windows events
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document#load_unload_events